# Google Maps API V2 : Different InfoWindow for each marker

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have managed to place a marker for each item in my database using their stored title and coordinates.

I am now trying to change the content of each InfoWindow so that it shows information related to each place (other than the title and snippet).

Basically, all the places stored on the map have an InfoWindow with the same kind of information in it (such as: price, opening time, closing time... etc). I wish to display different values for these fields - values that are stored in the database.

Here is some related code :

**Part of onCreate():**

> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
> ```
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     final MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
>     final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
>
>
>     map = mapFragment.getMap();
>     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
>     focusMapOnCurrentLocation();
>
>     // 39 - default marker height
>     // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge
>     mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));
>
>     this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
>     this.infoTitle = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
>
>     map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
>         @Override
>         public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
>             return null;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
>             infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
>             mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
>             return infoWindow;
>         }
>     });
> ```

**createMarkersFromJson():**

> ```
> void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
>     // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
>     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
>     int length = jsonArray.length();
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
>         // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
>         JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
>
>         int id = jsonObj.getInt("id");
>         String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
>         String address = jsonObj.getString("address");
>         String phone_number = jsonObj.getString("phone_number");
>         String city = jsonObj.getString("city");
>         String latitude = jsonObj.getString("lat");
>         String longitude = jsonObj.getString("long");
>         String price = jsonObj.getString("price");
>
>         Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>                 .title(name)
>                 .position(new LatLng(
>                         Double.parseDouble(latitude),
>                         Double.parseDouble(longitude)
>                 ))
>         );
>
>         // An example of what I am trying to do for all the places on my map: 
>         // this.price = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.price);
>         // this.price.setText(jsonObj.getString("price"));
>     }
> }
> ```

The problem is that the same InfoWindow is associated with all the markers. I am looking for a way to call setText() for each label that is in my InfoWindow. However, getInfoContents() only accepts a marker, and a marker cannot store this kind of data. Maybe I could use a HashMap?

Comment: have you code for that please add here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea of using map should work.You can store markers and jsonObjects as keys and values in a Map data structure. Below is sydo code:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    Map<Marker,JsonObject> data = createMapFromJSON();  

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        JsonObject d = data.get(marker);            
        if(d!=null){
            infoTitle.setText(d.getString("title"));
            //set all data
            otherViewInInfoWindow.setText(d.getString("address"));
            mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
            return infoWindow;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @GingerJim Please Add some more how do i complete i have same issue